# Correlation of a 1D array from beginning to all points, a kind of sliding correlation

Tags: python, numpy, correlation, sliding

I have a 1D array and want to find the correlation of the series of first 2 elements, then first 3 elements... until all elements.
I can do it with numpy in a loop; here is my code:

```
data = np.array([10,5,8,9,15,22,26,11,15,16,18,7,4,8,-2,-3,-4,-6,-2,0,10,0,5,8])
correl = np.zeros(data.shape)
for i in range(1, data.shape[0]):
     correl[i] = np.corrcoef(data[0: i+1], np.arange(i+1))[0, 1]
print(correl)
```

and the result is:

```
[ 0.    -1.    -0.397  0.     0.607  0.799  0.88   0.64   0.581  0.556
  0.574  0.322  0.078 -0.02  -0.237 -0.383 -0.489 -0.572 -0.614 -0.634
 -0.568 -0.59  -0.573 -0.533]
```

I wonder how I can make it in numpy without a loop, i.e. be smarter/more efficient
Any idea please?

Comment: Perhaps irrelevant to the question, but you are not really computing the correlation between elements in `data`. You are computing the correlation between `data[0, i+1]` and the array `[0, 1, 2, ... ,i]`.

Comment: You're totally right. That's what I try to make with a smart operation (nothing to to with autocorrelation and the like)